# Line break in MySql/php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've a form where I create different texts. To use line breaks correctly I'm sending the input through nl2br. It works perfectly, using this code:

```
$formSubject  = nl2br(htmlentities( $_POST["formSubject"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

The problem I'm having is that I also have an Edit function and when I open a text to edit I get the line breaks but also `<br/>` in the text (which  I don't want because the users of this will not be familiar with html) and if I save (even without changing anything) it will add another line break (which means double `<br/><br/>` if I open it to edit again. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove `<br/>` ([str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)) or all html tags ([strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)) before edits
or
you can use WYSYWIG Editor (like tinymce or ckeditor) to edit text with html tags

Comment: Thanks! Strip_tags() did exactly what I wanted.